# Class cast exception using Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I got a few instances of the following stack trace on Firebase. Nothing else that would hint at my app triggering anything specific. If anyone has seen this or has any information about how to resolve it I'd much appreciate it. Both traces were using version 10.2.1 of play-services-maps and play-services-location.

```
Exception java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.be cannot be cast to com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.at
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.co.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:911)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.co.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1046)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cc.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1196)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cc.b (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:21113)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.f (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1162)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:881)
```

and

```
Exception java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.dm cannot be cast to com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.aw
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.bb.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:161)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.model.at.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:500)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.d.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:562)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.g.handleMessage (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:2059)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.d.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:516)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.aa.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:114)
```

Comment: it may problem comes from proguard..is it release build app?

Comment: This is a debug build for my app (no proguard) but clearly a proguarded version of the maps api from Google.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Manufacturer: Archos, Model: BUSH SPIRA E4X,
Board: Ac55diselfie,
Android API: 23,
Android OS: 6.0.1,
Brand: Archos,
RAM: 3.55GB,
Orientation: Portrait,
VM free: 14.54MB,
VM total: 45.59MB,
VM max: 512MB. This was in release - minifyEnabled false

Comment: Any luck on this?  I am getting com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.al cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup when trying to show the map

Comment: Sorry, no progress. My company switched over to using Mapbox.